# MySQL: How to set Linesize and other environment parameters

Tags: mysql

I need to set linesize to some queries I perform which are quite important. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an equivalent output formatting in MySQL to Oracle's linesize & pagesize, I would suggest using raw output mode.  If you need line wrapping at a certain length rather than the full unwrapped line, you can pass it through a command line utility such as Unix `fmt`:

```
echo "SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1;" | mysql --raw --batch -uuser -p dbname | fmt --width=80
```